# Find the least distance in a matrix C++

Tags: c++, recursion

So I want to make a recursive C++ program to find the minimum distance a person should go from top to bottom of a matrix. The person can go downward, diagonal right, and diagonal left. I need to display the total distance and which number he went through. This code works if I'm trying to find the maximum distance, but got an error when i turn it into finding the minimum distance. Any idea?
Ps: I must use recursive function, no loops
Thanks!

```
   int SearchPath(int row_now, int col_now, int** arr, int row, int col, int total) {
    if (row_now == row - 1) {
        return total + arr[row_now][col_now];
    }
    int min = SearchPath(row_now + 1, col_now - 1, arr, row, col, total + arr[row_now][col_now]);
    if (col_now > 0) {
        int temp = SearchPath(row_now + 1, col_now, arr, row, col, total + arr[row_now][col_now]);
        if (temp<min)
            min = temp;
    }
    if (col_now < col - 1) {
        int temp = SearchPath(row_now + 1, col_now + 1, arr, row, col, total + arr[row_now][col_now]);
        if (temp<min)
            min = temp;
    }
    return min;
}

int Start(int start, int end, int** arr, int row, int col) {
    if (start == end)
        return 0;

    int min = SearchPath(0, start, arr, row, col, 0);
    int temp = Start(start + 1, end, arr, row, col);

    if (temp < min)
        return temp;
    else
        return min;
}
```

Comment: I think that you wanted to check "downward" `col_now` without `col_now > 0` guard and "diagonal left" `col_now - 1` with that guard.

Comment: This reads like it's from some contest/challenge/competitive coding/hacking site. Is it? If your goal is to learn C++, you won't learn anything there. In nearly all cases, like this one, the correct solution is based on a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is and attempt to code a brute-force approach, the program runs slow and fails for that reason. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from meaningless online contest sites [but only from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spotted two errors in your code, the first one is that you evaluating the diagonal left step without checking if such step can be made:

```
int min = SearchPath(row_now + 1, col_now - 1, arr, row, col, total + arr[row_now][col_now]);
```

And then you are evaluating the downward step only if diagonal left step can be made:

```
if (col_now > 0) {
    int temp = SearchPath(row_now + 1, col_now, arr, row, col, total + arr[row_now][col_now]);
    if (temp<min)
        min = temp;
}
```

The second issue is in Start function:

```
if (start == end)
    return 0;
```

The recursion exit condition returns 0 which most probably trumps valid paths. You have to:

1. Return the value so big that it won't be used by calling Start function:

   ```
    if (start == end)
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
   ```
2. Rewrite the Start function to not call the function at all when exit condition will be met:

   ```
    int Start(int start, int end, int** arr, int row, int col) {
        const int current_column_result = SearchPath(0, start, arr, row, col, 0);
        const int next_column = start + 1;

        if(end != next_column)
        {
            int next_column_result = Start(next_column, end, arr, row, col);

            if (next_column_result < current_column_result)
                return next_column_result;
        }
        return current_column_result;
    }
   ```

Also:

- Don't use names like `temp` in code that you want to share with anybody. It will help you to understand code better and hopefully spot your mistakes.
- Test your code:

  ```
    struct TwoDimmensionArray
    {
        TwoDimmensionArray(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> rows)
        {
             buff.reserve(rows.size());
             array = std::make_unique<int*[]>(rows.size());
             int** current_row = array.get();

             for(const auto& row : rows)
             {
                 auto new_row = std::make_unique<int[]>(row.size());

                 std::copy(std::begin(row), std::end(row), new_row.get());

                 *(current_row++) = new_row.get();

                 buff.push_back(std::move(new_row));
             }
         }

         operator int**() const
         {
             return array.get();
         }

         std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int[]>> buff;
         std::unique_ptr<int*[]> array;
     };

     int Start(int** arr, int row, int col)
     {
         return Start(0, col, arr, row, col);
     }

     void test_one_element()
     {
         assert(Start(TwoDimmensionArray{{1}}, 1, 1) == 1);
     }

     void test_three_elements()
     {
         assert(Start(TwoDimmensionArray{ {3,1,3},
                                          {3,2,1},
                                          {3,2,3} }, 3, 3) == 4);
     }

     int main()
     {
         test_one_element();
         test_three_elements();

         return 0;
     }
  ```